# Show template in embed view with all tabs in Docusign Via API

Tags: php, docusignapi

I have created a template where I have added the tabs for name, date, and signature. I want to show that template in embed view with all the tabs there. Here is the screenshot of the template http://nimb.ws/uFozXO

When I am sending the template in email to signer, it is showing all  tabs with name and date auto-filled but when I am showing the same template in embed view via API it is not showing any tab for name, date, and signature instead it is showing the left panel for user to select the tabs. 

How can I show the template with all tabs in embed view via API.

Comment: It sounds like your API call isn't correctly mapping the recipient to the template role. Can you provide an API log of the call you're making?

Comment: Thanks @Drew for your help. I got the solution. I just removed the recipient of the template from Docusign account for that template as you can see in the image http://nimb.ws/6bB0SK and then it was showing all  the tabs in embed view also. I think it had restricted the tabs for the recipient that's why it was not showing to other recipients.